# Django privilege to template

Tags: django

I have a separate control panel which will manage some user information and other data .Also in Django Group i have 3 groups such as 1) Owners ,2)Developers , 3 )Clients .

I have to give an access privilege of this control-panel template  to only Group owner and Developers .

Template Name : control_panel.html 
View : control-panel(request) : yet to implement the code for this .
Model : accessing 3 tables with product information and its prices

Answer (score 3):

If I were you, I would not tie access to groups, but rather to permissions, this way it is much more granular, and you can later allow other groups access to this view, by adding a permission to that group. In this case all you have to do is decorate your view like this:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import permission_required

@permission_required('some_permission')
def control_panel(request):
    # here goes your view
```

But if you prefer to use groups, you can do it like this:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import user_passes_test

@user_passes_test(labmda u: 'Owners' in u.groups.values_list('name', flat=True))
def control_panel(request):
    # here goes your view
```

Answer (score 0):

I implemented this way . this is more efficient method to do 

`@permission_required('admin.some_permission',login_url="/admin/permission_required_error")

def control_panel(request):
#your code here` 

If the user dont have the permission then it will redirect to the login_url location . Here we can Show the Description about this permission .

In the login_url View : 

`def permission_required_error(request):

    context={}

    next_page = request.GET.get('next', '')

    context={'next_page':next_page}

    return render_to_response ('permission_required_error.html', context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))`